# Webpack / babel-loader producing many errors in new project

Tags: webpack, babeljs, reactjs

I have a .jsx file that produces no errors during the webpack build process in one project. When I drop it in another project, with a different webpack config, it now produces a ton of errors, most of which seem like nit-picky syntax errors that should no way affect whether the file is able to run correctly.

Does someone know why the second project produces so many errors for the same file? What do I need to adjust in the webpack config or babel dependencies to not have webpack produce so many errors for syntax related items like indentation and whether I use var vs let?

Here is an example of some of the errors:

```
    1:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
    2:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
    3:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
    4:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
    4:4    error  LayoutStyles is defined but never used                           no-unused-vars
    5:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
    6:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
    6:4    error  LayoutSizes is defined but never used                            no-unused-vars
    7:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
    8:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
   10:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
   16:21   error  Missing function expression name                                 func-names
   17:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   20:24   error  Missing function expression name                                 func-names
   20:34   error  Missing space before opening brace                               space-before-blocks
   23:12   error  Missing function expression name                                 func-names
   24:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   24:8    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
   26:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   26:8    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
   27:12   error  Missing parentheses around multilines JSX                        react/wrap-multilines
   27:59   error  "optionStyle" used outside of binding context                    block-scoped-var
   27:59   error  optionStyle was used before it was defined                       no-use-before-define
   27:85   error  Missing function expression name                                 func-names
   27:95   error  Missing space before opening brace                               space-before-blocks
   27:118  error  Missing semicolon                                                semi
   30:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   30:8    error  Keyword "if" must be followed by whitespace                      space-after-keywords
   30:27   error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                              eqeqeq
   30:41   error  Missing space before opening brace                               space-before-blocks
   31:8    error  Expected indentation of 8 characters                             indent
   32:16   error  Missing parentheses around multilines JSX                        react/wrap-multilines
   32:62   error  "optionSelectedStyle" used outside of binding context            block-scoped-var
   33:33   error  "selectedPinkStyle" used outside of binding context              block-scoped-var
   35:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   37:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   37:8    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
   37:8    error  All "var" declarations must be at the top of the function scope  vars-on-top
   37:26   error  Trailing spaces not allowed                                      no-trailing-spaces
   38:12   error  Missing parentheses around multilines JSX                        react/wrap-multilines
   38:72   error  optionStyle was used before it was defined                       no-use-before-define
   38:72   error  "optionStyle" used outside of binding context                    block-scoped-var
   38:98   error  Missing function expression name                                 func-names
   38:108  error  Missing space before opening brace                               space-before-blocks
   38:128  error  Missing semicolon                                                semi
   40:29   error  Missing semicolon                                                semi
   41:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   41:8    error  Keyword "if" must be followed by whitespace                      space-after-keywords
   41:27   error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                              eqeqeq
   41:38   error  Missing space before opening brace                               space-before-blocks
   42:8    error  Expected indentation of 8 characters                             indent
   42:26   error  Trailing spaces not allowed                                      no-trailing-spaces
   43:16   error  Missing parentheses around multilines JSX                        react/wrap-multilines
   43:80   error  "optionSelectedStyle" used outside of binding context            block-scoped-var
   44:33   error  "optionIconSelectedStyle" used outside of binding context        block-scoped-var
   47:33   error  "selectedPinkStyle" used outside of binding context              block-scoped-var
   48:46   error  Trailing spaces not allowed                                      no-trailing-spaces
   49:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   51:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   51:8    error  All "var" declarations must be at the top of the function scope  vars-on-top
   51:8    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
   51:29   error  Trailing spaces not allowed                                      no-trailing-spaces
   52:12   error  Missing parentheses around multilines JSX                        react/wrap-multilines
   52:75   error  "optionStyle" used outside of binding context                    block-scoped-var
   52:75   error  optionStyle was used before it was defined                       no-use-before-define
   52:101  error  Missing function expression name                                 func-names
   52:111  error  Missing space before opening brace                               space-before-blocks
   52:134  error  Missing semicolon                                                semi
   55:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   55:8    error  Keyword "if" must be followed by whitespace                      space-after-keywords
   55:27   error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                              eqeqeq
   55:41   error  Missing space before opening brace                               space-before-blocks
   56:8    error  Expected indentation of 8 characters                             indent
   57:16   error  Missing parentheses around multilines JSX                        react/wrap-multilines
   57:80   error  "optionSelectedStyle" used outside of binding context            block-scoped-var
   58:33   error  "optionIconSelectedStyle" used outside of binding context        block-scoped-var
   61:33   error  "selectedPinkStyle" used outside of binding context              block-scoped-var
   62:58   error  Trailing spaces not allowed                                      no-trailing-spaces
   63:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   65:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   65:8    error  All "var" declarations must be at the top of the function scope  vars-on-top
   65:8    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
   65:26   error  Trailing spaces not allowed                                      no-trailing-spaces
   66:12   error  Missing parentheses around multilines JSX                        react/wrap-multilines
   66:72   error  "optionStyle" used outside of binding context                    block-scoped-var
   66:72   error  optionStyle was used before it was defined                       no-use-before-define
   66:98   error  Missing function expression name                                 func-names
   66:108  error  Missing space before opening brace                               space-before-blocks
   66:128  error  Missing semicolon                                                semi
   69:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   69:8    error  Keyword "if" must be followed by whitespace                      space-after-keywords
   69:27   error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                              eqeqeq
   69:38   error  Missing space before opening brace                               space-before-blocks
   70:8    error  Expected indentation of 8 characters                             indent
   70:26   error  Trailing spaces not allowed                                      no-trailing-spaces
   71:16   error  Missing parentheses around multilines JSX                        react/wrap-multilines
   71:80   error  "optionSelectedStyle" used outside of binding context            block-scoped-var
   72:33   error  "optionIconSelectedStyle" used outside of binding context        block-scoped-var
   75:33   error  "selectedPinkStyle" used outside of binding context              block-scoped-var
   77:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   79:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   79:8    error  All "var" declarations must be at the top of the function scope  vars-on-top
   79:8    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
   79:28   error  Trailing spaces not allowed                                      no-trailing-spaces
   80:12   error  Missing parentheses around multilines JSX                        react/wrap-multilines
   80:74   error  optionStyle was used before it was defined                       no-use-before-define
   80:74   error  "optionStyle" used outside of binding context                    block-scoped-var
   80:100  error  Missing function expression name                                 func-names
   80:110  error  Missing space before opening brace                               space-before-blocks
   80:132  error  Missing semicolon                                                semi
   83:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   83:8    error  Keyword "if" must be followed by whitespace                      space-after-keywords
   83:27   error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                              eqeqeq
   83:40   error  Missing space before opening brace                               space-before-blocks
   84:8    error  Expected indentation of 8 characters                             indent
   84:28   error  Trailing spaces not allowed                                      no-trailing-spaces
   85:16   error  Missing parentheses around multilines JSX                        react/wrap-multilines
   85:80   error  "optionSelectedStyle" used outside of binding context            block-scoped-var
   86:33   error  "optionIconSelectedStyle" used outside of binding context        block-scoped-var
   89:33   error  "selectedPinkStyle" used outside of binding context              block-scoped-var
   91:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   93:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   93:8    error  All "var" declarations must be at the top of the function scope  vars-on-top
   93:8    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
   94:12   error  Missing parentheses around multilines JSX                        react/wrap-multilines
   94:72   error  optionStyle was used before it was defined                       no-use-before-define
   94:72   error  "optionStyle" used outside of binding context                    block-scoped-var
   94:98   error  Missing function expression name                                 func-names
   94:108  error  Missing space before opening brace                               space-before-blocks
   94:128  error  Missing semicolon                                                semi
   96:29   error  Missing semicolon                                                semi
   97:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
   97:8    error  Keyword "if" must be followed by whitespace                      space-after-keywords
   97:27   error  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='                              eqeqeq
   97:38   error  Missing space before opening brace                               space-before-blocks
   98:8    error  Expected indentation of 8 characters                             indent
   98:26   error  Trailing spaces not allowed                                      no-trailing-spaces
   99:16   error  Missing parentheses around multilines JSX                        react/wrap-multilines
   99:80   error  "optionSelectedStyle" used outside of binding context            block-scoped-var
  100:33   error  "optionIconSelectedStyle" used outside of binding context        block-scoped-var
  103:33   error  "selectedPinkStyle" used outside of binding context              block-scoped-var
  105:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
  107:6    error  Expected indentation of 6 characters                             indent
  108:36   error  modeStyle was used before it was defined                         no-use-before-define
  108:36   error  "modeStyle" used outside of binding context                      block-scoped-var
  120:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
  131:1    error  Missing semicolon                                                semi
  133:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
  144:1    error  Missing semicolon                                                semi
  146:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
  149:1    error  Missing semicolon                                                semi
  151:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
  152:12   error  Missing space before value for key "display"                     key-spacing
  153:13   error  Missing space before value for key "position"                    key-spacing
  154:10   error  Missing space before value for key "width"                       key-spacing
  159:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
  159:4    error  optionArrowDownSmall is defined but never used                   no-unused-vars
  160:42   error  Infix operators must be spaced                                   space-infix-ops
  161:1    error  Missing semicolon                                                semi
  163:0    error  Unexpected var, use let or const instead                         no-var
  165:1    error  Missing semicolon                                                semi
```

Here is my webpack config for the project where the file produces no errors:

```js
'use strict';

var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'sourcemap',
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, 
        loaders: [
          'babel'
        ]
      },
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loaders: ['babel'] },
      { 
        test: /\.less$/, 
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader' 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      { 
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
      } // inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        "root.jQuery": "jquery"
    })
  ]
};
```

And these are the babel related dependencies for the project with no errors:

```
"babel": "^5.6.14",
"babel-core": "^5.6.15",
"babel-eslint": "^3.1.18",
"babel-jest": "^5.0.1",
"babel-loader": "^5.3.1",
"babel-plugin-object-assign": "^1.1.0",
"bundle-loader": "^0.5.4",
"babel-plugin-flow-comments": "^1.0.9",
```

This is the webpack config for the project that produces hundreds of errors for the same file:

```js
var path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var webpack = require("webpack");

var assetsPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "public", "assets");
var publicPath = "assets/";

var commonLoaders = [
  {
    /*
     * TC39 categorises proposals for babel in 4 stages
     * Read more http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/
     */
    test: /\.js$|\.jsx$/,
    loader: "babel-loader?stage=0",
    include: path.join(__dirname, "..",  "app")
  },
  { 
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
  }, // inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
  { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html-loader" },
  { 
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
  },
  { test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?module&localIdentName=[local]__[hash:base64:5]' +
      '&sourceMap!sass?sourceMap&outputStyle=expanded' +
      '&includePaths[]=' + (path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules')))
  }
];

module.exports = [
  {
    // The configuration for the client
    name: "browser",
    /* The entry point of the bundle
     * Entry points for multi page app could be more complex
     * A good example of entry points would be:
     * entry: {
     *   pageA: "./pageA",
     *   pageB: "./pageB",
     *   pageC: "./pageC",
     *   adminPageA: "./adminPageA",
     *   adminPageB: "./adminPageB",
     *   adminPageC: "./adminPageC"
     * }
     *
     * We can then proceed to optimize what are the common chunks
     * plugins: [
     *  new CommonsChunkPlugin("admin-commons.js", ["adminPageA", "adminPageB"]),
     *  new CommonsChunkPlugin("common.js", ["pageA", "pageB", "admin-commons.js"], 2),
     *  new CommonsChunkPlugin("c-commons.js", ["pageC", "adminPageC"]);
     * ]
     */
    context: path.join(__dirname, "..", "app"),
    entry: {
      app: "./client"
    },
    output: {
      // The output directory as absolute path
      path: assetsPath,
      // The filename of the entry chunk as relative path inside the output.path directory
      filename: "[name].js",
      // The output path from the view of the Javascript
      publicPath: publicPath

    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
      preLoaders: [{
        test: /\.js$|\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["eslint"]
      }],
      loaders: commonLoaders
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.react.js', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss'],
      modulesDirectories: [
        "app", "node_modules"
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // extract inline css from modules into separate files
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles/main.css"),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ]
  }, {
    // The configuration for the server-side rendering
    name: "server-side rendering",
    context: path.join(__dirname, "..", "app"),
    entry: {
      app: "./server",
      header: "./elements/Header"
    },
    target: "node",
    output: {
      // The output directory as absolute path
      path: assetsPath,
      // The filename of the entry chunk as relative path inside the output.path directory
      filename: "[name].server.js",
      // The output path from the view of the Javascript
      publicPath: publicPath,
      libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
    },
    externals: [
      {
        'alt/AltContainer': true,
        'react/addons': true
      },
      /^[a-z\-0-9]+$/
    ],
    module: {
      loaders: commonLoaders
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.react.js', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss'],
      modulesDirectories: [
        "app", "node_modules"
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // extract inline css from modules into separate files
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles/main.css"),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ]
  }
];
```

And these are the babel dependencies in the project that produces errors:

```
"babel-core": "^5.5.4",
"babel-eslint": "^3.1.14",
"babel-loader": "^5.1.4",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second configuration you are running eslint...

```
preLoaders: [{
  test: /\.js$|\.jsx$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loaders: ["eslint"]
}],
```

EsLint will check your code for common problems and enforce a chosen style format.  This is why you are getting all those errors.

Read more on linting here: http://eslint.org/docs/about/

If you are importing the code into an existing project with this configuration why not just fix the "nitpick" issues?  The original developer may have wanted a consistent style across the code base.